# How many 9-digit decimal integers have no 0’s and no 1’s but have at least one 2 and at least one 3?

Tags: combinatorics

I came up with $8^{9} - 6^{9}$, where $8^{9}$ = $9$-digit decimal integers with no $0$'s and $6^{9}$ = all $9$-digit decimal integers with no $2$'s and no $3$'s.

Comment: And your question is? And regardless of what your question is, an explanation for how you obtained this number would probably be fruitful, if just so everyone doesn't have to repeat work (or it could help critique said work if it's wrong).

Comment: I was wondering if I arrived at the right answer. I subtracted the complement of 9-digit decimal integers that have at least one 2 and at least one 3 from all 9-digit decimal integers with no 0's and no 1's.

Answer (score 2):

There are $8^9$ numbers not containing ${\tt 0}$ or ${\tt 1}$. Among these there are $7^9$ not containing ${\tt 2}$ and another $7^9$ not containing ${\tt 3}$. Subtracting these from the $8^9$ eliminates the $6^9$ numbers containing neither ${\tt 2}$ nor ${\tt 3}$ twice. The number $N$ we are interested in therefore is given by
$$N=8^9-2\cdot 7^9+6^9=63\,588\,210\ .$$